# How to track a point on a sprite based on color

Tags: python, pygame

I have a small sprite to represent a car, with six points surrounding it for spatial awareness. How would I track the points based on their color so I could test collision with a rectangle?

The left two points are pure magenta, the front two pure red, and the right two pure green * (255, 0, 255) ; (255, 0, 0) ; (0, 255, 0)

```
    im = Image.open('CarSprite.png')
    im = im.convert('RGBA')

    data = np.array(im)
    red, green, blue, alpha = data.T

    black_areas = (red == 0) & (blue == 0) & (green == 0)
    data[..., :-1][black_areas.T] = (random.randint(50,250), random.randint(50,250), random.randint(50,250)) # Converts black to random colors

    im2 = Image.fromarray(data)
    mode = im2.mode
    size = im2.size
    data = im2.tobytes()
```

Comment: ```track the points based on their color so I could test collision with a rectangle?``` Why would you need colour? Surely some coords x, y and size are enough for collision?

Comment: I guess using bounding box is better to find the collision

Answer (score 3):

I realise I am not answering your question directly...

The best way forward with this sort of collision is firstly check for a collision on the bounding rectangle of the sprite.  This is an efficient check, because if the base-rectangle has not collided, there is no reason to check the six control points.

The Pygame [rect class](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) already supports this sort of detection with the `colliderect()` member function.

Once the code determines that a base-level collision has occurred, then use the [rect.collidepoint()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) function with each of your six control points (obviously accounting for the current position of your sprite).

You may also want to investigate using a [collision bitmask](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html?highlight=bitmask) for more accurate pixel-level collisions.